# Let $G$ be a non abelian simple group. Show that ${\rm Aut}(G^n)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(G) \wr{\rm Sym}(n).$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group, simple-groups, wreath-product

I got this question but don't know how to answer it.

Let $G$ be a non abelian simple group. Show that ${\rm Aut}(G^n)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(G) \wr{\rm Sym}(n)$.

I already know that ${\rm Aut}(G)^n$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G^n)$.

Comment: The answer you posted should be part of the question.

Comment: How did this problem arise?

Comment: Since [$A_5$ is the smallest simple nonabelian group](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/A5_is_the_simple_non-abelian_group_of_smallest_order), it might be worth experimenting with it to shed light on things.

Comment: Prove first that the $n$ direct factors are the only minimal normal subgroups of $G^n$. So any automorphism of $G^n$ must permute the direct factors. The subgroup ${\rm Aut}(G)^n$ of ${\rm Aut}(G^n)$ that you have identified is the subgroup that fixes all of the direct factors, so the full automorphism group is a semidirect product of this with $S_n$ - i.e. ${\rm Aut}(G) \wr S_n$.

Comment: I understand that every minimal normal subgroup is isomorphic to G. But I am not sure how the isomorphism actually looks.